# Google Line Chart - Year displaying as 2K

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm trying to use google line chart and everything works great except all the year's at the x axis are displayed as 2K instead of e.g. 2015, 2016.
Here are my test page: http://bokhald.trubador.is/bokhald/testGraf.html

Here are my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

                  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Altogether');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 1');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 2');

                  data.addRows([

                            [2009, 21, 13, 8], [2010, 32, 17, 15], 
                            [2011, 48, 38, 10], [2012, 53, 34, 19], 
                            [2013, 59, 44, 15], [2014, 56, 46, 10],
                            [2015, 56, 48, 8], [2016, 6, 5, 1]

                  ]);

                  var options = {
                    height: 500,
                    axes: {
                    }
                  };

                  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('my_chart'));

                  chart.draw(data, options);
                }
                    $(window).resize(function(){
                    drawChart();
                    });
              </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my_chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the date in the addColum to date and make the dates new javascript date objects, set format to yyyy for the x colons

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

                  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                  data.addColumn('date', 'Year');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Altogether');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 1');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 2');

        data.addRows([
         [new Date(2009,1,1), 21, 13, 8], [new Date(2010,1,1), 32, 17, 15], 
                        [new Date(2011,1,1), 48, 38, 10], [new Date(2012,1,1), 53, 34, 19], 
                        [new Date(2013,1,1), 59, 44, 15], [new Date(2014,1,1), 56, 46, 10],
                        [new Date(2015,1,1), 56, 48, 8], [new Date(2016,1,1), 6, 5, 1]
        ]);

                  var options = {
                    width: 1000,
                    height:500,
                    hAxis: {
            format: 'yyyy',
            gridlines: {count: 15}
          },
                    axes: {
                    }
                  };

                  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('my_chart'));

                  chart.draw(data, options);
                }
                    $(window).resize(function(){
                    drawChart();
                    });
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

https://jsfiddle.net/rzqa598j/2/

Comment: Thank you for your reply madalin, can you show me where you would put this in my code above?

Comment: replace the dates in `data.addRows`

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that but It's still showing 2K.
See here: http://bokhald.trubador.is/bokhald/testGraf.html

Comment: If I put date instead of number in my data.addColumn the chart are not showing (blank page)
data.addColumn('number', 'Year'); to data.addColumn('date', 'Year');

See here:
http://bokhald.trubador.is/bokhald/testGraf.html

Comment: i  can't see the page you have some dns problems

Comment: Sorry, here are new path:
http://trubador.is/testGraf.html
And here are the version with number not date
http://trubador.is/testGraf2.html

Comment: It's woriking! Thanks alot Madalin :)